# How to use function on every item row in specific column with Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple DataFrame in Pandas that one of the column contains date in this format day-month-year.
I need to make another column that contains which weekday is that. I wrote this function that works with simple argument like '12-3-1999':

```
def convert_date_to_weekday(date_string):
  # convert string to date object
  date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
  # convert date object to weekday string
  print(date_object.strftime("%A"))
```

Unfortunetely this doesn't work:

```
df['Weekday'] = convert_date_to_weekday(df['Date'])
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) , which also a recommended way with pandas

```
def convert_date_to_weekday(date_string):
  # convert string to date object
  date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
  # convert date object to weekday string
  # print(date_object.strftime("%A"))
  return date_object.strftime("%A") 


df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: convert_date_to_weekday(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: convert_date_to_weekday(x))
```

and use return in your function instead of print

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I don't know about this lambda syntax) I guess there are still many things before me in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def convert_date_to_weekday(date_string):
  # convert string to date object
  date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
  # convert date object to weekday string
  return date_object.strftime("%A")
```

Along with your apply line.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method of the pandas dataframe:

```
df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].apply(convert_date_to_weekday)
```

But your `convert_date_to_weekday` should return the result instead of printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function.

```
df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda d: convert_date_to_weekday(d))
```

Also, change your `print(date_object.strftime("%A"))`  to `return date_object.strftime("%A")`